# computation P=L

Tags: time-complexity, polynomial-time-reductions

i have the following question which I'm having some hard time to solve:

> prove: if every two Languages $A$ and $B$ that have a polynomial reduction ($A$ to $B$) also have a log space reduction ($A$ to $B$), then $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{L}$.

Comment: Hint: consider (nontrivial) $A\in\mathsf{P}$ and $B\in\mathsf{L}$. What sort of reducibility do you know - without any additional hypotheses whatsoever - exists from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: A similar question was recently posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/150184/if-every-2-languages-are-that-have-polynomial-reduction-have-log-space-reduction

Comment: See here
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/150184/if-every-2-languages-are-that-have-polynomial-reduction-have-log-space-reduction/150195#150195