# If every 2 languages are that have Polynomial reduction have LOG SPACE reduction does L=P?

Tags: complexity-theory

If every 2 languages $A,B$ that have Polynomial reduction $A<_pB$ have LOG SPACE reduction $A<_LB$, does $\mathsf{L}=\mathsf{P}$?

Comment: A similar question was recently posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/150179/computation-p-l

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.
We know that L is included in P (hierarchy of languages)
We'll show that P is included in L:

Let A be Polynomial and B L
We can reduce A to B Polynomialy (hierarchy)
Thus we can reduce A to B LogSPACE hence A is included in B as required

Comment: I'm not convinced. If $A\in P$ and $B\in Logspace$ then it is not obvious that $A<_pB$, which is the hypothesis in the question. It then doesn't follow that $A<_{Logspace}B$, from which it would follow that $A\in Logspace$. The hypothesis is only that _if_ all pairs of polynomial-reducible languages are also logspace-reducible, then [...]. But to show $P\subseteq \text{Logspace}$, we also need the hypothesis that some language in $A$ is polynomial-reducible to a language in $Logspace$. So it doesn't seem to me that $P\subseteq \text{Logspace}$ follows.

Comment: Every language in $\mathrm{P}$ is reducible to any other language in $\mathrm{P}$ in polynomial time with a trivial reduction. The rest follows from the hypothesis.